# Office 365 - Tenant Administrator - Trust Add In

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Can someone please tell me who is the Tenant Admin that can trust add-ins we are trying to add. We have tried logging in as every single user and none have the ability to trust the add in we are trying to add.

> Your tenant administrator has to approve this app.

[image: Who is tenant administrator?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MS has recently made a change, which seems to have gone quietly. If you need any tenant level permission for your App only provider hosted app, you need to add permission in tenant admin site and not in any of the site collection

http://sharepointitis.blogspot.com.au/2016/09/app-only-policy-with-tenant-level.html

I posted my origial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43905720/316199)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have seen that post and as far as I can tell none of these users are admin in site collections. I could be wrong but I'm not 100% sure how to verify since I'm not really a SharePoint guy

Comment: The part of that post I don't understand is this part: So what changed? Well, MS has recently made a change, which seems to have gone quietly. If you need any tenant level permission for your App only provider hosted app, you need to add permission in tenant admin site and not in any of the site collection! Well lets try that then... What does this mean?

Comment: We are using the same Permission Request XML using tenant rather than site collection.

Comment: Keep in mind we are using localhost url because our app is not a web site (has no ui) it is a Windows service (self hosted WCF services)

Comment: This is my post with more detail on what we are trying to do https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/215371/66772

Comment: did you open the admin page from this URL? https://[tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked the difference in the URL. Did not notice the "-admin". Thanks for your time and patience Ali.